# C client socket program timesout

Tags: c, sockets

I have a very simple socket client program that I want to use to ping my mail server (as an example) to make sure it's alive and responding. I am using the following code to connect:

```
portno=25;
sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
if (sockfd<0) error("Cannot open socket");
server=gethostbyname(argv[2]);
if (server==NULL) {
        printf("Error: No such host exists\n");
        exit(3);
}
bzero((char*)&srvr,sizeof(srvr));
srvr.sin_family=AF_INET;
bcopy((char*)&server->h_addr,(char*)&srvr.sin_addr.s_addr,server->h_length);
srvr.sin_port=htons(portno);
if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr*)&srvr,sizeof(srvr)) <0) error("Error connecting");
```

I pass the server name (as localhost) on the command line as the second parameter. It always hangs in the connect call. I have tried to also connect to one of google's mail servers with the same result.

I am able to telnet into port 25 on both my local server and the google server and issue the HELO command and get a response. I am running the program as root.

I am unsure how to proceed further in order to determine the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [This](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo) is usually recommended....as `gethostbyname` is obsolete....

Comment: @Recker I knew that, I had just cut and pasted some old code because I figured it would get me up and running quicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is apparently not complete. You might want to make a couple of debug messaging including a check for the correct input to `gethostbyname()`.

You should normally use IPPROTO_TCP as protocol, instead of 0.

```
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)
```

You might want to use a tool like `strace` to see more details about how the system calls went on.

It's usually better to use `getaddrinfo()`.

```
const char *node = "www.fedoraproject.org";
const char *service = "http";
struct addrinfo hints = {
    .ai_family = AF_UNSPEC,
    .ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM,
    .ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP,
    .ai_flags = AI_ADDRCONFIG,
    .ai_canonname = NULL,
    .ai_addr = NULL,
    .ai_next = NULL
};


struct addrinfo *result;
int error;

error = getaddrinfo(node, service, &hints, &result);

struct addrinfo *item;
int sock;

for (item = result; item; item = item->ai_next) {
    sock = socket(item->ai_family, item->ai_socktype, item->ai_protocol);

    if (sock == -1)
        continue;

    if (connect(sock, item->ai_addr, item->ai_addrlen) != -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Connected successfully.");
        break;
    }

    close(sock);
}

freeaddrinfo(result);
```

See: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Networking/NameResolution#Connecting_to_services_using_getaddrinfo.28.29

Comment: Thanks. I updated my program with the newer stuff in the example and seems to me working now. Thanks.